# Unable to connect localstack dynamodb from lambda

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, localstack

I am getting connection refused error while connecting to dynamodb (localstack) from lambda written in Typescript

I use localstack to emulate the AWS resource and below is how I am accessing the dynamodb

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import {
  DynamoDBDocumentClient,
  ScanCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({
    region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:4566',


});


const dynamo = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
const TABLE_NAME = process.env.TABLE_NAME || '';


export const handler = async (event: any) => {

    try {
        console.log('connecting to dyname db: ' +  TABLE_NAME)
        var body = await dynamo.send(
            new ScanCommand({ TableName: TABLE_NAME })
          );          
        const response = body?.Items;
        return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(response) };
    } catch (dbError) {  
        console.log('Unable to get the data from dyname db: ' +  TABLE_NAME)      
        return { statusCode: 500, body: JSON.stringify(dbError) };
    }
  };
```

and below is the error what I am getting.

```
{
    "errno": -111,
    "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
    "syscall": "connect",
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4566,
    "$metadata": {
        "attempts": 3,
        "totalRetryDelay": 32
    }
}
```

where as I am able to get the details through AWS CLI command.

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 dynamodb scan --table-name <table-name>
```

Comment: Where do you run your Lambda function code? Locally or is it deployed to AWS? If it is deployed, it won't be able to access your local machine without using tools like ngrok.

Comment: I trying to test the lambda locally by deploying into localstack

Answer (score 0):

if your lambda code is running inside localstack

The LocalStack instance/resources is available at the domain **localhost.localstack.cloud**. All subdomains of **localhost.localstack.cloud** also resolve to the LocalStack instance.

I was able to connect to localstack dynamo after modifying the DynamoDBClient creation like below.

```
const client = new DynamoDBClient({
  region:process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
  endpoint: 'http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566'
});
```

[Localstack documentation : Accessing LocalStack via the endpoint URL](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/network-troubleshooting/endpoint-url/)